# Bypassing java login in maven

Tags: java, maven

Currently using open source project (https://github.com/mcollinge/07kit/tree/master/src/main)
And when i build the application, it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/f2zh5a
The thing is, the API is on their side (`public static final String API_URL = "https://api.somesite.com/user";`)
Their API is down. Therefore i cannot register on their site, to go through the logging in process.
Would there be any way to bypass login?
Providing LoginController class code below.

```
public class LoginController extends Controller<LoginView> {

public static final String API_URL = "";

private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);
private LoginView view;

public LoginController() {
    ControllerManager.add(LoginController.class, this);
}


public void show() {
    try {
        if (Session.get().getApiToken() != null) {
            logger.info("Existing API token found - trying to retrieve account info...");
            if (loadAccount(Session.get().getApiToken(), true, Session.get().getEmail().getValue())) {
                logger.info("Logged in with pre-existing key.");
                return;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Failed to authenticate.", e);
    }

    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    int centerX = (toolkit.getScreenSize().width / 2) - (getComponent().getWidth() / 2);
    int centerY = (toolkit.getScreenSize().height / 2) - (getComponent().getHeight() / 2);
    getComponent().setLocation(centerX, centerY);
    getComponent().setIconImage(Application.ICON_IMAGE);
    getComponent().setVisible(true);
}

public void login(String email, String password, boolean rememberMe) {
    try {
        SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                HttpResponse response = Executor.newInstance(HttpUtil.getClient()).execute(Request.Post(API_URL + "/token")
                        .bodyString(JacksonUtil.serialize(new CreateTokenRequest(email, password)), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)).returnResponse();
                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    UserToken tokenResponse = JacksonUtil.deserialize(
                            EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()),
                            UserToken.class);
                    if (loadAccount(tokenResponse.getUuid(), rememberMe, email)) {
                        logger.info("Logged in.");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                logger.error("Invalid login, response: [" + response.toString() + "]");
                getComponent().getStatusLbl().setText("Status: Invalid login");
                return null;
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Oops.", e);
        getComponent().getStatusLbl().setText("Status: Error logging in");
    }
}

private boolean loadAccount(String uuid, boolean rememberMe, String email) throws IOException {
    HttpResponse getAccountResponse = Executor.newInstance(HttpUtil.getClient()).execute(Request.Get(API_URL)
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + uuid)).returnResponse();
    if (getAccountResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        logger.info("Processed login [" + getAccountResponse.toString() + "]");

        UserAccount account = JacksonUtil.deserialize(
                EntityUtils.toString(getAccountResponse.getEntity()),
                UserAccount.class);
        if (account != null && account.getStatus() == UserAccount.Status.ACTIVE &&
                account.getType() != null) {
            getComponent().getStatusLbl().setText("Status: Logged in");
            getComponent().dispose();

            Session.get().setUserAccount(account);

            Session.get().setApiToken(uuid);
            Property emailProperty = Session.get().getEmail();
            Property apiKeyProperty = Session.get().getApiKey();
            if (rememberMe) {
                if (emailProperty == null) {
                    emailProperty = new Property(Session.EMAIL_PROPERTY_KEY, email);
                    emailProperty.save();
                } else {
                    emailProperty.setValue(email);
                    emailProperty.save();
                }

                if (apiKeyProperty == null) {
                    apiKeyProperty = new Property(Session.API_KEY_PROPERTY_KEY, uuid);
                    apiKeyProperty.save();
                } else {
                    apiKeyProperty.setValue(uuid);
                    apiKeyProperty.save();
                }
            } else {
                if (emailProperty != null) {
                    emailProperty.remove();
                }

                if (apiKeyProperty != null) {
                    apiKeyProperty.remove();
                }
            }
            Session.get().onAuthenticated();
            ControllerManager.get(MainController.class).show();
            return true;
        } else {
            getComponent().getStatusLbl().setText("Status: Only BETA users can login");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public LoginView getComponent() {
    if (view == null) {
        view = new LoginView(this);
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Looks like your `login` and `loadAccount` methods are using an `HttpResponse` that comes from calling an `HttpUtil.getClient()` method. So you could try mocking the client returned from `HttpUtil.getClient()` so that it will return fake data. Try looking into [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock)

Comment: @D.B Thanks, that worked!